# Use Office 365 user login to authenticate in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-active-directory, office365, azure-ad-b2c

I'm working on a serverless desktop application for a client in WPF and they have an enterprise level Office 365 license and all their users are on it. I want to use the same user logins to authenticate to my app, I'm not sure if I can do this directly through the WPF app against Azure Active Directory or Office 365 APIs, or do absolutely need a server somewhere (in ASP.NET for example) to handle the authentication redirection and everything using Azure Active Directory or Azure AD B2C.

If you guys have any recommendation, that would be great. 
Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

WPF is native so you would need to use the ADAL / MSAL library to connect to Azure AD.
as e.g. [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2/).

O365 users are already in Azure AD so B2C is not going to help you here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer